# Exportar archivo plano con caracteres especiales en C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Tengo una consulta desde *SQL*, que lo muestro en un *GridView* en una página web (*ASP.NET*) y desde allí lo exporto a un archivo plano delimitado con *C#* y tengo problemas con los acentos y caracteres especiales.

Por ejemplo, la palabra `MUÑOZ`, que la `Ñ`  debe ocupar un espacio, me sale `MU&#209;OZ` y desborda la delimitación del archivo.

```
protected void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string nombre = "Archivo" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    //Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename="+nombre+".txt");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
         gvDatos.AllowPaging = false;
         gvDatos.DataBind();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     //añadimos la cabecera desde el texbox

            string cab = txtCabecera.Text;

            sb.Append(cab);

        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");

        CargarDatos();

        for (int i = 0; i < gvDatos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < gvDatos.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                //add separator
                sb.Append(gvDatos.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text);
            }
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné cambiando la propiedad del BoundField del Gridview HtmlEncode de true a false.
`<asp:BoundField DataField="contribuyente" HeaderText="CONTRIBUYENTE" 
                HtmlEncode="False" />`

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y no he logrado resolverlo

Answer (score 1):

Esto [se debe al encoding](https://www.gestiweb.com/?q=content/problemas-html-acentos-y-e%C3%B1es-charset-utf-8-iso-8859-1). Deberías de utilizar `utf-8` que es el encoding estandard.

Aqui:

```
Response.Charset = "";
```

Deberia de ser:

```
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
```

Tambien agrega esta etiqueta debajo del `head` solo por si acaso:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
 ...
</html>
```